# Angular 2 and redux Integration issue

Tags: angular, webpack, redux, rxjs

I am new to Angular 2, Redux and RxJs applications. I grabbed the sample application from git hub https://github.com/CronixMicroSystems/ng2-typescript-boilerplateand try to run with **npm run dev** but the console throws the below error.

**(13,55): error TS2345: Argument of type '{
 counter: (state: ICounterRecord, action: Action) => ICounterRecord; 
 session: (state: ISessionRe...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObjec
'.
  Property 'router' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(state: string, action: RouterAction) => string' is not assignable to type 'Reducer'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'RouterAction'.
          Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'RouterAction'.
            Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action'.
webpack: Failed to compile.**

Could you please help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue. Though it only happens when I use Typescript 2.4, if I use 2.3.1 it goes away.

The sample application you linked to has the Typescript dependency set to `next` so it will grab the latest version available. What you could do is set the typescript version to 2.3.1 in your `package.json` and run `yarn install`. Then try to run the app again with `yarn run dev`